# Animated Tkinter Toplevel GUI multi-child

Tags: python, matplotlib, user-interface, animation, tkinter

I shortened the code a lot and marked (###) it where I think the problem could be. The problem with the following code is: I try to code an animated Tkinter multi-toplevel GUI. One open toplevel-child works fine. As soon as I open a second child-window, the first child-window dies and the second child-window gets messed up with values from the first etc, etc.

How can I separate them? Is the problem here:
self.Satellit = tk.Toplevel(root, bd = 5, relief = GROOVE)?

Code:

```
def realtime_Position(self,i):
                
        def Aktualisierung():
            try:
                self.Object.get_tk_widget().pack_forget()
            except AttributeError: 
                pass
            
            figure = plt.Figure(figsize=(5,4), dpi=100, tight_layout=True)
            ax1 = figure.add_subplot(111)
            self.Object = FigureCanvasTkAgg(figure, master=self.Satellit)
            self.Object.get_tk_widget().pack(side=LEFT, fill=BOTH)

            ax1.set_title(i+ " realtime Chart")
            figure.autofmt_xdate(rotation=45)
### HERE-
            self.Satellit.after(realtime_Abrufrate_1, Aktualisierung)

        self.Satellit = tk.Toplevel(root, bd = 5, relief = GROOVE)
        self.Satellit.iconbitmap('bull_trend.ico')
        self.Satellit.title(i+" Realtime")
### -TO HERE
        
        figure = plt.Figure(figsize=(5,4), dpi=100, tight_layout=True)
        ax1 = figure.add_subplot(111)
        self.Object = FigureCanvasTkAgg(figure, master=self.Satellit)
        self.Object.get_tk_widget().pack(side=LEFT, fill=BOTH)
        
### AND HERE-
        self.Satellit.after(realtime_Abrufrate_1, Aktualisierung) 
### -TO HERE
```

Comment: This appears to just be part of a class definition. Are you calling this function multiple times, or are you creating multiple instances of the class? If you're calling this function multiple times, then you keep overwriting `self.Satellit` with each call unless there's some code somewhere that deletes the old window before creating a new one.

Comment: Thank you for your help! Yes, I´m calling this function multiple times (iterating with `i`). Can I write a kind of loop changing `self.Satellit`? (maybe like: `b50 = Button(f5, text=Code, command=lambda Code=Code:Programm.realtime_Position(P, Code))`)? Thank you!

Comment: please post an [mvce](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) if you need help